# Class/package: design vs code

Tags: expl3, package-writing, documentclass-writing

`LaTeX3` team often reminds us: "Classes really should be about formatting/style/etc., not functionality. The latter should be added by packages, which ideally would be independent of the classes they are used with [...] [P]ackages should be using `expl3` code, classes should be using document- or design-level interfaces which might be implemented in `expl3`" (see e.g. https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/887#issuecomment-827484540).

Suppose a class should insert a graphic on the first page of the document if this graphic is found and otherwise should display an admonition (in addition to a warning in the log file). Is it design or functionality?

Comment: we need a site "tex philosophie" ... but I would say it is design of the (title) page.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hence for a package, I guess. But it seems to contradict what is said in `clsguide.pdf`: "The first thing to do when you want to put some new LaTeX commands in a file is to decide whether it should be a document class or a package. The rule of thumb is: “If the commands could be used with any document class, then make them a package; and if not, then make them a class”."

Comment: I don't see a contraditcion there, adding a logo to the front page is as much about design as choosing the fonts and page size etc.  Note also since there is no standard design level interface written in expl3 you the distinctions are not as sharp as they will be eventually and they will never be completlely sharp.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And the code that displays either the graphic or the admonition has to be in the class, isn't it?

Comment: yes but I don't think that is a problem. you could abstract out a generic "include image or make warning" function and put it in a package then use that but I don't see any problem with not doing that. In practice such things are not easy to make generic.